# Arriving in France before the start of a Student Visa. Can I go to the UK and come back to France?

Tags: visas, france, us-citizens, study

I'm American and currently applying for a Student Long Stay Visa in France (>90 days; it's a 2 year Master's program). My visa appointment with the consulate is in mid-July. My school starts on September 16th, and I've stated on the application that I plan to go to France on September 1st.

Well it turns out that it would be better for me to go to France August 1st. I was wondering if it's possible that I could go to France on a tourist visit (which does not require a visa for stays <90 days) and then take a short weekend trip to the UK (at the end of August) before returning and presenting them with my student visa?

I know that I technically cannot combine a long stay visa with a tourist visit. However this isn't *technically* combining the two as I would be leaving the Schengen territory and re-entering, right?

I can't easily ask to make the start of my visa August 1st because my boyfriend recently got the attestation d'accueil (proof of accommodation for the first 3 months of my stay) validated by the mairie and the start date for this document is on September 1st.

Comment: Make sure you have proof of travel to UK, immigration in France may want to see that. But yes that's fine, you can enter from anywhere outside Schengen.

Comment: @BritishSam, please post that as an answer.

Comment: I disagree with BritishSam. Immigration officers within and outside Schengen are very aware of people trying to manipulate the system in ways described by the O/P. Arrival in France before your visa is valid will raise concerns that you may stay beyond its expiry date, coupled with the fact that you appear to have a boy friend residing in France. A short trip to the UK is a common ruse that UK immigration are wise to. They will not see you as a genuine visitor but as someone seeking to circumvent Schengen rules. Source: Have seen people try this and get deported.

Comment: _"I know that I technically cannot combine a long stay visa with a tourist visit."_ Do you have a reference for this claim? It is one that is often made, but we have never been able to trace it to any actual Schengen legislation, nor do I recall ever hearing of someone actually getting into trouble for switching from visa-free to long-stay while still within the zone.

Comment: @canonacer If you are a genuine visitor it's fine. People trying to do what their visa is for early is not allowed, they need to prove they aren't doing that. Personally yes I'd just go when my visa starts, but theres nothing legally stopping the person. Obviously it's down to the immigration officer.

Comment: @lana Did you end up entering early? How was your interaction with the border control officer?

Comment: It is quite common for students to visit their country of study before the start of their program. Just make sure you can show proof of funds.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I see no one answered so I'm going to add some information I believe is pertinent. I received the following email from the Austrian BMI regarding entering visa-fee before a Visa D is valid. Keep in mind this is a translation from the original email in german:

> If the visa-free stay is short or the travel purpose for the visa-free stay is different from the one for the visa D stay (eg first tourism, then study/employment), the entry would be lawful. Whereby a visa-free entry (observing the rule: 90 days per period of 180 days) and the subsequent stay with a visa D is seamlessly possible.

Suggesting that a third-country national with visa-free privileges may enter before validity date on the D Visa and that a "Visa Run" to the UK is not technically necessary